# Converting Bytes to Fixed point

Tags: python

I'm reading some bytes from a binary file and I'm trying to convert them to decimals. They are big endian, so I try to unpack them as `unpack('>f',bytes)`, but I'm getting the wrong result.

According to the specification I should be looking for

> Fixed point numbers with 8 bits before the binary point and 24 bits
> after the binary point. Three guard bits are reserved in the points to
> eliminate most concerns over arithmetic overflow. Hence, the range for each component is 0xF0000000 to 0x0FFFFFFF representing a range of -16 to 16.

As an example I'm using `0x00d4f9c1`, which should give me 0,831936, but I'm getting 1,95587[...]e-38.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `f` designator is for floating point, which is entirely different from fixed point.  You just need to convert that to an integer and divide by 2**24.

```
>>> x = 0x00d4f9c1
>>> x/(1<<24)
0.8319359421730042
>>>
```

Comment: Not just any floating point, but IEEE 754

Comment: For all practical purposes, there is no other kind.